# With use JSON.parse(), how to take value in multi dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Before use JSON.parse, an JSON array is shown below:

```
var temp = {
      "queries": [
    {
      "sample_size": 3,
      "results": [
        {
          "name": "temperature",
          "tags": {
            "Tag": [
              "temperature"
            ]
           },
           "values": [
            [
              1452221580000,
              27.5
            ],
            [
              1452221640000,
              27.1
            ],
            [
              1452221700000,
              27.3
            ]
           ]
        ]}
     ]}
    }
```

I need to get the value from the array, so I use JSON.parse().

```
var jsonparse_temp = JSON.parse(temp);
var dataNum = jsonparse_temp ['queries']['sample_size'];
var timestamp1 = jsonparse_temp ['queries']['results']['value'][0][0]
var value1 = jsonparse_temp ['queries']['results']['value'][0][1]
```

After that, is `value1` equal `27.5`?
I'm not sure this way could sign the value to variable.

Comment: `temp` is a Javascript object. [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) expects a string in JSON format.

Comment: `temp.queries.samplesize`, `temp.queries.results[0].values[1][0]`

Comment: Furthermore, `results` is an array, so in your code (when accessing the original object) a `[0]` after `['results']` is missing.

Comment: Hmm, is this a valid object? Queries has the opening brace of an array and the closing brace of an object. Typo?

Comment: You're right, at first glance it looks to be valid but badly formatted. Upon inspection the braces do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a JSON string it's a well-formed object no need to parse it. There is nested array so you need to get the object element from the array using the index.

```js
var temp = {
  "queries": [{
    "sample_size": 3,
    "results": [{
      "name": "temperature",
      "tags": {
        "Tag": [
          "temperature"
        ]
      },
      "values": [
        [
          1452221580000,
          27.5
        ],
        [
          1452221640000,
          27.1
        ],
        [
          1452221700000,
          27.3
        ]
      ]
    }]
  }]

};

// using bracket notation
var dataNum = temp['queries'][0]['sample_size'];
var timestamp1 = temp['queries'][0]['results'][0]['values'][0][0]
var value1 = temp['queries'][0]['results'][0]['values'][0][1];

console.log(dataNum, timestamp1, value1);

// using dot notation
var dataNum1 = temp.queries[0].sample_size;
var timestamp11 = temp.queries[0].results[0].values[0][0]
var value11 = temp.queries[0].results[0].values[0][1];


console.log(dataNum1, timestamp11, value11);
```

Comment: Without the parse, how could I take the value? I try to use `temp.queries.results.values` , but useless.

Comment: Could you make a sample?

Comment: @JK.Lin :  check the snippet

Answer (score 1):

> an JSON array is shown below:

That isn't JSON. That is a JavaScript object. There is no JSON anywhere in your question.

> ```
> var jsonparse_temp = JSON.parse(temp);
> ```

This will return `undefined` since `temp` is not a string of JSON.

> ```
> ['queries']['sample_size'];
> ```

queries is an array, not an object. It doesn't have a `sample_size` property.

The first value in that array is an object which *does* have that property.

You need to access each level of the data structure in order. You can't skip levels.

```
var dataNum = temp.queries[0].sample_size;
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```js
var dataNum = temp['queries']['sample_size'];
var timestamp1 = temp['queries']['results']['value'][0][0]
var value1 = temp['queries']['results']['value'][0][1]
```

Comment: The object is not [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) but a well structured Javascript object which is accessible immediately with [standard accessors (keys)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and the [array with indexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements).